# Finding tetration in a multiplicative group modulo p

Tags: discrete-logarithm

I have a variant on the discrete logarithm problem, involving finding tetration in a multiplicative cyclic group of integers modulo a large prime $p$:

$$a = x^x \mod p$$

Where $a$ and $p$ are known, and $p$ is not necessarily a safe prime. Can $x$ efficiently be found or is this at least as hard as the DLP?

Comment: Like DLP in the multiplicative group of integers modulo n, except that the base must equal the exponent.

Comment: In DLP we know that base, In this case, there can be more than one pair for a given $a$ or none.

Comment: " Can x efficiently be found or is this at least as hard as the DLP?" Probably, it is neither one nor the other, but somewhere in between. For some values $a$, it might have multiple solutions or none - so maybe it is easy to find the solution for some and difficult for others. Since the set of solutions don't have a group structure (or something similar), I can't think of a way to define any security property, which would work for all $a$.

Comment: Also please note that, algebraically speaking, the exponent will not belong to the same group as the base. Furthermore, the group of integers modulo a prime p, will not be cyclic for any primes greater than 3. There will however always be cyclic sub groups of some prime order q, such that q divides (p-1). Consequently the problem has to be redefined to make better sense.

Comment: @HenrickHellström Every $\mathbb F_q^\ast$ is cyclic.

Comment: @yyyyyyy Not using the terminology with which I am familiar, but that is perhaps beside the point. Every such group has a generator, but not every element except 1 is a generator. The distinction is relevant in this context, because if $a$ belongs to a small sub group, finding a solution $x$ ought to be relatively easy.

Comment: Usually tetration, sometimes written ${^nx}$, means $\underbrace{x^{x^{{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^x}}}}}}_{\text{$n$ times}}$ rather than just $x^x$.  The function $x \mapsto x^x$ is sometimes called the ‘self-power map’.  But it's not defined on $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ without a choice of map to $\mathbb Z/\phi(p)\mathbb Z$.  For example, if $p = 11$, for $x = 19$, do you take it to be $(19 \bmod p)^{(19 \bmod p) \bmod \phi(p)} \bmod p = 8^8 \bmod 11 = 5$, or do you take it to be $(19 \bmod p)^{19 \bmod \phi(p)} \bmod p = 8^9 \bmod 11 = 7$?

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71258/what-can-be-said-about-the-self-power-map-on-groups-based-on-dlp But in my case I try to recover $x$ from $h \equiv g^x \pmod p$ so the iterative procedure looks as $g^{g^x} \pmod p$ until you hit $x$. I call it 'self-power map' as Squeamish Ossifrage said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it's not quite clear what the problem is, but here's an easy algorithm for the (arguably) most natural interpretation.

Given any prime $p$ and integer $a$, the following procedure finds an *integer* $x\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$ such that
$$ x^x\equiv a\pmod p \,\text. $$

---

1. Pick some positive integer $e$ coprime to $p-1$. (For example, $e=1$ always works.)
2. Write the prospective solution as $x=e+k(p{-}1)$ with $k\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$.
3. Since the order of $x$ must be a divisor of $p-1$, the equation becomes
   $$(e+k(p{-}1))^{e}\bmod p=a \,\text. $$
   Raise everything to the power of $f:=e^{-1}\bmod(p{-}1)$ to obtain
   $$ e+k(p{-}1) \equiv a^f \pmod p \,\text. $$
4. Simply solve this congruence for $k$, that is, compute
   $$ k := (e-a^f)\bmod p \,\text. $$
5. Output $x:=e+k(p{-}1)$.

---

Note that the expected size of $x$ is approximately $p^2$.